# ¿Cómo sumar en mysql valores para un MAX(en otra columna)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Digamos que tengo estas dos columnas:

```
|----------------|----------------|
|   Columna1     |    Columna2    |
|----------------|----------------|
|      3         |      50        |
|      1         |      150       |
|      2         |      200       |
|      3         |      750       |
|      1         |      180       |
|----------------|----------------|
```

Para el valor máximo de la columna 1 quiero sumar los valores de la columna2.

Es decir, primero quiero seleccionar el mayor valor de la Columna1 (digamos que se llama maxvalor)

Luego, quiero tomar todos los valores de la columna2 en donde columna1=maxvalor, y sumarlos.

- En este caso el máximo de la columna 1 es 3
- Los valores de la columna 2 cuya columna1 es igual a 3 son 50 y 750
- Trato de hacer un query que, en este caso, me diese 800.

He intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM(Columna2) FROM tabla where MAX(Columna1) GROUP BY Columna1
```

.. eso me da este error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of
>   group function

Comment: No veo porque votar para cerrar esta pregunta, está bastante claro lo que el autor quiere

Comment: Sería bueno que quien votó negativo y para cerrar la pregunta diese un breve comentario acerca del por qué :D !

Comment: @Jorius he retirado mi voto negativo :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que te falta, seria algo así:

```
 SELECT SUM(Columna2)
 FROM tabla 
 WHERE Columna1 = (Select MAX(Columna1) FROM tabla)
 GROUP BY Columna1
```

en la subconsulta buscas cual es la mayor columna1 y despues solamente comparas si la columna1 que estas es la mayor

Comment: Gracias, me funciona!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que **no puedes** hacer un `WHERE MAX(Columna1)`, debes realizar una subconsulta de la siguiente forma, seleccionamos la `Columna2` y la sumamos, luego dentro del `WHERE` realizamos la *subconsulta* para traer el `MAX` de la `Columna1`,

```
SELECT 
    Columna1, SUM(Columna2)
FROM
    tabla
WHERE
    (SELECT 
            MAX(Columna1)
        FROM
            tabla)
GROUP BY Columna1;
```

La consulta anterior te dará un resultado más o menos parecido:

```
__________________________
|Columna1 | SUM(Columna2)|
__________________________
|1        | 330          |
__________________________
|2        | 200          |
__________________________
|3        | 800          |
__________________________
```